# How do I filter my table to show the result in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a source table:

[image]

I need to map it to destination table where I would choose one unique ID and color with minimum of status value and shape with maximum of status value of that ID. For example,
[image]

Comment: where is destination table?

Comment: once you select id then select minimum of status value from all data and shape with maximum of status value from all data??? and insert into destination table??

Comment: if you are going through id min max then output  to destination table is i 1 black circle!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: But I need minimum and maximum value of status for that specific ID , I would have two more rows for ID 2 and 3.

Comment: Yes you are correct @nikhilsugandh

Comment: For future reference, please do not post images for code or data. It just makes it harder for people to test their solutions before posting them. Help us to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Oracle Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) in a subquery. No joins necessary.

```
select
r.id,
r.color,
r.shape
from
(
    select
    s.id,
    first_value(s.color) over (partition by s.id order by s.status) as color,
    first_value(s.shape) over (partition by s.id order by s.status desc) as shape,
    row_number() over (partition by s.id order by s.status) as row_index
    from shapes s
) r
where r.row_index = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay I am finally able to write it down:

```
Select x.id, x.shape,y.color 
from 
     (Select id ,shape 
      from Shapes
      where status in ( Select max (status) 
                        from shapes 
                        group  by id)
        ) x 
  join 
        (Select id , color 
          from shapes 
          where status in (Select min(status) 
                           from shapes 
                           group by id )
       ) y 
on x.id = y.id;
```

Shorter answers are welcome

Comment: This does not produce your required output from the posted sample data.